# Multicols with includegraphics in bottom of the page

Tags: graphics, multicol

In my document i have a picture in a multicols env.

The problem is that Latex put the multicols in the bottom of the page and the picture is going under the footer.
Latex should create a new page.
Can you help me ?

thank you

Here is a demo code

**Edit MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2cm, top=1cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Etape : 1}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Etape : 2}
\begin{multicols}{2}
     \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}

\vfill
\columnbreak
text text text 
\end{multicols}

\section{Etape : 3}
\begin{multicols}{2}
     \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}

\vfill
\columnbreak
text text text 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Original MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2cm, top=1cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\begin{document}
\section{Etape : 1}
{\lipsum[1-5]}

\section{Etape : 2}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

\vfill
\columnbreak
text text text 
\end{multicols}

\section{Etape : 3}
\begin{multicols}{2}
     \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

\vfill
\columnbreak
text text text 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when i compile your code it is fine (no problem) may be because i don't have the images you use. If all what you need is to start new page before multicol you can use `\newpage`.

Comment: I edit your post  (sorry if this not what you mean)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, i have added a screenshot with my contents. The problem is that the picture on the 1st column doesn't care about the footer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution. the `multicols` environment has two optional arguments

`\begin{multicols}{columns}[text in full width][vertical space at least]`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, left=2cm, top=1cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm}

\newsavebox\mt

\begin{document}
\section{Etape : 1}
\lipsum[1-5]


\sbox\mt{\parbox{\textwidth}{\section{Etape : 2}\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}}}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Etape : 2}][\ht\mt]
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}
\vfill
\columnbreak
text text text 
\end{multicols}


\sbox\mt{\parbox{\textwidth}{\section{Etape : 3}\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}}}
\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Etape : 3}][\ht\mt]
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image}
\vfill
\columnbreak
text text text 
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, it's almost working, just seems that it doesn't take in account the height of the section title. So i still can have some problems. Maybe it is possible to add the height of the section title in the \ht\mt ? but how ? thank you

Comment: @PeterRoger i will update my answer.

Comment: @PeterRoger done

Comment: Thanks, but it adds two times the Section name and the Section in the mt sbox move the picture on the right. I tried to remove the Section name declared on the multicols arguments, but the one on the mt box still move the picture

Comment: I can't see what you mean. Did you compile my code as it is? here the save box is used only for measuring, section and image to be used explicitly inside multicols.

Comment: Sorry, missed that :) thank you it's working